# Ubercart Feed Mappers Importing Attributes - How to

Tags: import, drupal-7, ubercart

I have a Drupal 7 instance with Ubercart 3, I'm also using the Ubercart Feed Mappers module to map out the importing of product fields, I have all the fields, images and categories working well but not attributes.

I've searched high and low for an answer or a short how to for importing attributes and multiple attributes for each product but with no success, anyone out there know how?